# understanding workings of cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to change some stores procedures and query's for better performance. For some part, it's rewriting cursor syntax. To do this,I must fully understand how they work. I tried this simple ETL example, but it does not give me the expected result. Basically, doing an UPSERT here with a cursor.

Example code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Destination 
(PersonID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(10), LastName VARCHAR (10))
 INSERT INTO #Destination VALUES (101, 'M', 'Donalds')
 INSERT INTO #Destination VALUES (102, NULL, 'Richards')
 INSERT INTO #Destination VALUES (103, 'Rianna', 'Lock')
 INSERT INTO #Destination VALUES (104, 'Leo', 'Svensson')

 CREATE TABLE #SourceTable 
 (PersonID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(10), LastName VARCHAR (10))
 INSERT INTO #Destination VALUES (102, 'Diana', 'Richards')
 INSERT INTO #SourceTable VALUES (103, 'Rianna', 'Locks')
 INSERT INTO #SourceTable VALUES (106, 'Cleo', 'Davung')

  DECLARE @PersonID INT
  DECLARE @Firstname VARCHAR (10)
  DECLARE @Lastname VARCHAR (10)

  DECLARE SimpleCursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT PersonID, FirstName, LastName 
  FROM #SourceTable

  Open SimpleCursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM SimpleCursor INTO @PersonID, @Firstname, @Lastname
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN
  IF EXISTS ( SELECT PersonID FROM #Destination
              WHERE PersonID = @PersonID )
    UPDATE #Destination  
    SET #Destination.FirstName = #SourceTable.FirstName,
        #Destination.LastName = #SourceTable.LastName
    FROM #SourceTable
    WHERE #Destination.PersonID = #SourceTable.PersonID
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO #Destination
    SELECT PersonID, Firstname, Lastname FROM #SourceTable

  FETCH NEXT FROM SimpleCursor INTO @PersonID, @Firstname, @Lastname
  END

  CLOSE SimpleCursor
  DEALLOCATE SimpleCursor

SELECT * FROM #Destination
```

What am I missing here? I am not updating anything, while PersonID 102 and 103 do exist.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your first `INSERT` after `CREATE TABLE #SourceTable` has `#Destination` as target. Is that intensional?

Comment: There are a few syntax flaws here that will make this work ... oddly. As written above, the cursor will update all rows that match each time it finds a match - which is odd, and too much effort. It should be updating from the fetched variables `@PersonID`, `@FirstName` and `@LastName`. There's also a syntax error in your table creation script where your insert is targeting the wrong table.

Comment: A `CURSOR` is a terrible way to do this; SQL Server's forté is not iterative tasks. If you really want to improve performance you should be looking at a dataset approach for things like this. Have you considered using `MERGE`?

Comment: Yeah either  a MERGE or the standard style upsert would be a way better way of handling this. Who cares if this cursor doesn't work, it shouldn't be used here anyway.

Comment: @Larnu: trying to understand cursors, to get rid of them. By the way, I thought merge had some nasty side-effects, potentially causing deadlocks.

Comment: @Larnu https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Trying to understand a `CURSOR` is fine, but it's also very important to understand when to (or maybe more importantly when not to) use them. A process such as this is certainly not something that should be completed via a `CURSOR`. I admit `MERGE` wasn't "great" in SQL Server 2008, however, a lot of those "features" have been addressed or fixed in later versions (I think there was quite a few changes in 2012 iirc). If, however, you don't trust `MERGE` then go with traditional upsert methodology as @SeanLange mentioned; not it a `CURSOR`.

Comment: That article was written initially based on 2008, and then updated with 2012 (it notes some of its fixes you'll see).

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the info. Just to clarify, I am not trying to do this process with a cursor. Iamusing this fictional example, to try and understand cursors better. Hopefully, this better understanding will enhance my capabilities to remove cursors in more complex statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the variables you fetched the values into in your `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements. Try:

```
...
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM #Destination
                  WHERE PersonID = @PersonID)
BEGIN
  UPDATE #Destination
         SET FirstName = @FirstName,
             LastName = @LastName
         WHERE PersonID = @PersonID;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #Destination
              (PersonID,
               FirstName,
               LastName)
              VALUES (@PersonID,
                      @FirstName,
                      @LastName);
END;
...
```